# R Simplifying data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-cleaning

I have a csv that has two columns of data, of which I want to plot both lines to compare the difference in values.  However, when generating the data, I wanted a large sample size, so the file contains a million entries. In my ignorance of R plot rendering, I decided to read in all the data, and then plot the million point lines.

I've gone through several questions but don't see anything that quite fits what I need. Also, I am currently trying to glean information from [Introduction to data cleaning with R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/de_Jonge+van_der_Loo-Introduction_to_data_cleaning_with_R.pdf), but having difficulty understanding it.

What I'd like to do is use one out of every 10 rows in my data, and use those as the data to plot with (100k items should be a lot better than 1M items, right?). What would be the best way to do that.  Is that actually the best way to simplify the data, are there better alternatives to my approach?

Sample Data:

```
OptionA, OptionB
1,0,
23,0,
4,0,
5,1,
20091,0,
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you supplied a small sample of the your data plus the code you want to run. To get started, if your data frame is `df` and you want to randomly sample 10% of the rows: `df[sample(1:nrow(df), floor(nrow(df)/10)),]`.

Comment: @eipi10 Added in sample data, but for code, I didn't know how exactly to run it, that's why I said "I looked here at these questions, and there at this pdf to get started, but still a bit confused"

Comment: For example, `plot(df[sample(1:nrow(df), floor(nrow(df)/10)),c("OptionA","OptionB")])` will plot a random 10% of your data.

Comment: @eipi10 Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Still pretty new to R, and couldn't think of the word `sample` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this in R (Google the `sample` function), but to get every 10th row, assuming your data is called `data`:

```
data[(1:100000)*10,]
```

It is as easy as that. `1:10000` generates a list of numbers from 1 to 100000. Then those number are multiplied by 10, giving you 10, 20, ... 1000000. Those are the rows, and the `,` with nothing after means all columns. So you end up with every 10th row and all columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, that helps a lot `sample` was the word I was looking for.

Comment: Or `df[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(df), by = 10),]`